# How to prevent modification to array data?

Tags: c++, constants

Say I have a class that looks like this (this is just an example):

```
class A {
    double *ptr;
public:
    A() : ptr( new double[100] ) {}
    A( const A &other ) {
        other.ptr[7] = 15;
    }
    void doNotChangeMyData() const {
        ptr[43] = 14;
    }
    void changeMyData() {
        ptr[43] = 14;
    }
    ~A() { delete[] ptr; }
};
```

The `const` in both the copy constructor and the `doNotChangeMyData` function make it so that `ptr` cannot be changed; however, this still allows me to modify the contents of the array pointed to by `ptr`.

Is there a way to prevent the contents of `ptr`'s array from being changed in `const` instances only, short of "being careful" (or changing away from raw pointer)?

I know I could do something like

```
void doNotChangeMyData() const {
    const double *const ptr = this->ptr;
    ptr[43] = 14; // then this would fail to compile
}
```

But I'd rather not have to ...

Comment: you could use a `std::vector`

Comment: `std::vector::operator[]()` can modify values right ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Edited question so not an option ;) It's more a theoretical question, but yes, `vector` would work.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul sure, but `std::vector::operator[]() const` returns a `const` reference

Comment: @ChrisMM what I expected, just wanted to mention the elephant in the room :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointers do not propagate `const`. Adding `const` to the type `double*` yields `double* const`, which results in a non-`const` lvalue when dereferenced.

Instead, you can use a `std::vector`:

```
class A {
    std::vector<double> data(100);
public:
    // no explicit copy ctor or dtor
};
```

a `std::array`:

```
class A {
    std::array<double, 100> data{};
public:
    // no explicit copy ctor or dtor
};
```

or a builtin array (not recommended):

```
class A {
    double data[100] {};
public:
    // no explicit copy ctor or dtor
};
```

All of the three options propagate `const`.

If you *really* want to use pointers (not recommended), consider using a `std::unique_ptr` to avoid manual memory management. You can use the `std::experimental::propagate_const` wrapper from the library fundamentals 2 TS: (using raw arrays with `unique_ptr` has some complications, as mentioned in a comment below)

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>

class A {
    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<std::array<double, 100>>> ptr;
public:
    A()
        : ptr{std::make_unique<std::array<double, 100>>()}
    {
    }
    // manual copy ctor
    A(const A& other)
        : ptr{std::make_unique<std::array<double, 100>>(*other.ptr)}
    {
    }
    // defaulted move ctor & dtor
    // assignment operator, etc.
    // ...
};
```

It's not in the standard yet, but many compilers support it. Of course, this approach is inferior to the proper containers.

Comment: trying to do this without changing the underlying data type, more a theoretical question than anything. If not possible, then I'll accept it as not possible.

Comment: @ChrisMM I've updated the answer with a pointer solution. But why :)

Comment: "Why" is hard to answer, more a curiosity. "Built-in array" or `std::array` don't work, if you don't know size at compile time. `vector` adds overhead; `unique_ptr` doesn't add overhead but if the pointer needs to be shared, then you need `shared_ptr` which does add overhead. I don't think VS currently supports `propagate_const` (at least the header file referred to by cppreference doesn't exist with `/std:c++latest`) :(

Comment: @ChrisMM The overhead of `vector` is often overestimated TBH, especially compared to the effort of manual memory management. Also, if you share the pointers manually, you have to use a reference count, so the overhead is not peculiar to `shared_ptr`. I didn’t know that VS doesn’t support `propagate_const` yet (GCC and Clang both support it IIRC), but it is not hard to roll out our own according to the spec.

Comment: I agree that the overhead is minimal, but there are reasons to use raw pointers when performance is critical (memory and time). I sometimes use a `vector` then take its contents via `.data()` or `&vec[0]` and work directly with that instead. In the case of the shared, I often have one owner of the pointer which creates and deletes, but other classes share the data.

Comment: `std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<double[]>> ptr;` does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/3b18rc .

Comment: @fwyzard Indeed - I've taken the easy approach of using `std::array` instead.